# Python: List is a int, TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, python-2.x

Is a dynamic solution for kp problem. I have a problem with the type when do for the generator for compression. This is clearly a list but it says is an integer, I've looked everywhere but can not find a solution. Could I help?

```
import itertools

def kpdynamic1(max_weight, iterable):
    '''
    Dynamic solution kp 
    :param max_weight: int
    '''  
    K = [(0, [(0, 0)])]

    # debug
    print type(iterable)
    print iterable

    for w in range(1, max_weight + 1):
        l = [(0, [(0, 0)])] + \
            [(K[w - weight][0] + value, K[w - weight][1] + [(value, weight)])
            for (value, weight) in
            itertools.compress(iterable,
                                (1 if (weight <= w) else 0
                                 for (value, weight) in iterable))]
        K += max(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return K[max_weight]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_size = 30
    values = (3, 1.9, 30)
    sizes = (3, 2, 14)

    iterable = zip(values, sizes)

    out = kpdynamic1(max_size, iterable)
```

OUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
..., line ..
out = kpdynamic1(max_size, iterable)
..., line .. 
for (value, weight) in iterable))]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
<type 'list'>
[(3, 3), (1.9, 2), (30, 14)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending `K` with a single element from `l`:

```
K += max(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

where `l` contains tuples. Note that I said **extending**, not *appending*; the elements *contained in that one maximum tuple* are added, not the tuple itself:

```
>>> K = []
>>> K += (0, 0)
>>> K
[0, 0]
```

As such you end up with single integers in `K`, which you then try to treat as sequences:

```
[(K[w - weight][0] + value, K[w - weight][1] + [(value, weight)])
```

Here `K[...]` returns an integer, so `K[...][0]` will fail.

Instead of extending with `+=`, use `K.append()`:

```
K.append(max(l, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

or wrap the result of `max()` in a single-element list:

```
K += [max(l, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

With that change your function produces a result:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def kpdynamic1(max_weight, iterable):
...     K = [(0, [(0, 0)])]
...     for w in range(1, max_weight + 1):
...         l = [(0, [(0, 0)])] + \
...             [(K[w - weight][0] + value, K[w - weight][1] + [(value, weight)])
...             for (value, weight) in
...             itertools.compress(iterable,
...                                 (1 if (weight <= w) else 0
...                                  for (value, weight) in iterable))]
...         K.append(max(l, key=lambda x: x[0]))
...     return K[max_weight]
... 
>>> max_size = 30
>>> values = (3, 1.9, 30)
>>> sizes = (3, 2, 14)
>>> iterable = zip(values, sizes)
>>> kpdynamic1(max_size, iterable)
(61.9, [(0, 0), (30, 14), (30, 14), (1.9, 2)])
```